# Can Oracle forms 11g connect to DB2 or SQL Server?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I just want to know whether Oracle forms 11g supports other databases like DB2, SQL Server etc.
Also does Oracle forms 11g supports Oracle database 9i or 10g apart from 11g?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Oracle middleware [certification spreadsheet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/downloads/fmw-11gr1certmatrix.xls) (once you have opened the spreadsheet, click "Current System (Server and Client) Certification" and then search for Oracle Forms) you will see that Oracle Forms is certified against the following database versions:

```
Oracle 10.2.0.4+
Oracle 11.1.0.7+
Oracle 11.2.0.1+
```

Oracle Forms may work with earlier versions than what have been listed but if you run into problems you won't be able to get support from Oracle.

Oracle Forms 11g can be used against non-oracle datasources. To get started look in the Forms help, Google, and the [Oracle Forms forum on OTN](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=82)  for transactional triggers.

However my personal opinion is whilst Oracle Forms is a great tool with Oracle Database you should seriously think about whether it is the right tool for working with other datasources.